# Lazy Load XT not working on ui route change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lazy-loading

I am using [lazy load xt](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt) which is jQuery plugin for lazy loading my images and videos. Its working fine when the page is loaded(read: refreshed).

However, my app is a AngularJS SPA and I am using `ui.router` for routing. When a template is loaded through the routing mechanism, the lazy load plugin doesn't work. However, when I refresh the page it starts working.

My guess is that this is happening because lazy load xt only fires on window's onload event. How do I make it work/trigger it with angular routing?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your to angular run

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event) {
      $(window).lazyLoadXT();
      $(window).lazyLoadXT({show: true});


    });
```